# Sith Typically Left Handed According To Comic Books

Tags: star-wars, sith

<s>Darth Vader</s>Anakin Skywalker is left handed in the movies.

Does this also hold true for the comic books?

In addition are Sith more likely to be left handed?

Comment: Before anyone starts downvoting, look up the etymology of the word "sinister".

Comment: @Mr Lister, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Any left handed tendencies you saw in regard to Anakin Skywalker is related to the fact that Hayden is left handed.

Comment: @scott.korin that makes sense thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Sith do not appear to be predisposed to left-handedness

It’s not clear that Vader *is* left-handed in the movies. Here he is fighting with his right hand in his duel with Luke Skywalker on Bespin, for example.

[image]

He also is portrayed as right-handed in the Marvel *Star Wars* comics.

[image]

As for other Sith, Darth Sidious at least sometimes fights with his right hand only:

[image]

According to Nick Gillard, the stunt coordinator, Sidious is in fact ambidextrous:

> Pertaining to whether Sidious is right-handed or left-handed with a
> lightsaber, he’s ambidextrous. He’s just that good.

(This seems to be sourced from a Hyperspace chat, but I can’t find a screenshot etc. of the original).

Dooku also appears to be right-handed, or at least employing a right-handed fighting style:

[image]

Note that this also shows Anakin holding his lightsaber with his right hand.

Darth Maul, on the other hand, *is* left-handed:

[image]

These comprise the sum total of the Sith we have seen in canon (Pong Krell, for example, being a dubious example).

That said, there is some (non-canon) evidence of left-handedness among Sith. In Legends, the Sith species (which predated the Sith as an organization of Dark Side users) tended to be left-handed:

> A peculiarity of the Sith people was their innate tendency toward
> left-handedness. This led to their creation of the lanvarok, a
> forearm-mounted weapon adapted strictly for left-handed use (human Sith
> Lords later crafted a right-handed version).
>
> <sub>Evil Never Dies: The Sith Dynasties</sub>

Comment: Should I remove the part about Darth Vader being left handed.  For some reason I thought he was in the prequels.

Comment: @William - Well, he might fight using a left-handed style sometimes, or gesture with his left hand, or so forth.

Comment: These 2 statements seem to conflict with each other. Sith do not appear to be predisposed to left-handedness.  In Legends, the Sith species (which predated the Sith as an organization of Dark Side users) tended to be left-handed:

Comment: @William - One refers to an organization in Disney canon. The other refers to a *species* that is no longer canon, and further specifically notes that there were lots of right-handed human Sith.

Comment: Just to clarify there are no other Sith's that are left handed execpt darth maul according to the comic books even?

Comment: @William - Well, I haven’t looked at Maul, Sidious, and Dooku in the comics, but I suspect they accord with their film depictions.

Comment: I have accepted your answer if you don't mind checking at some point it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, here's an interesting question. Does the left-handedness refer to their use of a lightsaber, or their use of the force? Because logically, if they're holding a lightsaber in their right hand, would they not then be using their left hand to use their force powers?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo that would mean Anakin and obi wan are also left handed which wouldn't make sense would it?